# Animate change between background images?

Tags: css

Im using a green image as a repeating background tile on my site. When you click an element the background changes to a blue repeating image.

I want to animate the colour change. Can this be done with CSS3? Could one solution be to use a black and white image for the tillable pattern and colourise it with CSS3?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a tile `background-image` with a solid colour, give it a transparent background. This will then allow you to transition the `background-color` using CSS3 to achieve the same effect:

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/yLLNa/**

### CSS

```
html {
    background-color: red;
    transition: background-color 1s linear;
}

html:hover {
    background-color: blue;
}
```